# Eclipse plugin,how to run a wizard with popup action?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I wrote a wizard, now I want use a popup menu to launch the wizard.
I make a action like this:

```
/**
 * @see IActionDelegate#run(IAction)
 */
public void run(IAction action) {

    MyWizard wizard = new MyWizard ();
    wizard.init(PlatformUI.getWorkbench(), new StructuredSelection());

    WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wizard);
    dialog.create();
    dialog.getShell().setText(wizard.getWindowTitle());
    int result = dialog.open();
}
```

but it didn't work.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Actions are legacy. Did you try Commands? See [here](http://eclipse-tips.com/tips/37-contributing-workbench-wizards-thru-commands) for an example